# Why does this work in Python? Creating a instance, setting a non existent attribute in that class, then printing that attribute through the instance

Tags: python, oop

I was watching a Youtube tutorial about python classes.

This is the code he wrote.

```
class Tweet :
  pass

a = Tweet()

a.message = '140 chars'

print (a.message)

# This works

print(Tweet.message)

# This doesn't
```

I understand why printing tweet.message doesn't work (or at least I think I do if its as straightforward and simple as it seems) but why does printing a.message does? I'm assuming this is something to do with how python works but what is it?

Actually now that I'm thinking about it, maybe I have it wrong. I thought Tweet.Message doesnt print because tweet does have a message you can set. But does python automatically create the ability to do a.message ? So the reason tweet.message doesnt print it because that is only a blueprint, you can only retrieve data from instances, not the actual class itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python allows dynamically adding new attributes to an object, even if it's not "declared" in the class signature, or assigned during object initialization in the `__init__` method.

When you execute the assignment `a.message = "..."`, the `message` attribute is added only to the `a` object, but not to the `Tweet` class, nor to any other objects with the same type. If you have another object `b` of `Tweet` type and you try to access its `message` attribute directly, you would get an `AttributeError`.

Here's a comprehensive example:

```py
class Tweet:
  def __init__(self):
    self.user = "default_user"

a = Tweet()
print(a.user)     # "default_user"
a.message = "140 chars"
print(a.message)  # "140 chars"

b = Tweet()
print(b.user)     # "default_user"
print(b.message)  # AttributeError: 'Tweet' object has no attribute 'message'

print(Tweet.user)     # AttributeError: type object 'Tweet' has no attribute 'user'
print(Tweet.message)  # AttributeError: type object 'Tweet' has no attribute 'message'
```

Comment: So is it because it is coding like tweet is an instance name for an object but Tweet is really a class

Comment: `__init__` is just a convenience for executing code immediately after an object is created. There is no difference between `self.user = "default_user"` and `a.user = "default_user"`; both are just setting (possibly creating) an attribute `user` on whatever object `self` or `a` refers to.

Comment: @user7959439 I'm not sure I understand what you said. `Tweet` here is a class, and `a` and `b` are instances of the `Tweet` class. We can also say that `a` and `b` are objects of `Tweet` type, and that basically means the same thing. I think @chepner made a very good point: setting an attribute on an instance (or object) always only sets that instance, and does not affect its class.

Comment: Just a note, [`object.__setattr__(self, name, value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) is the method acutally called when an attribute assignment, like `self.user = "default_user"` or `a.user = "default_user"`, is attempted. Without customization, the normal mechanism of this method is to store the value in the instance dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

`Tweet.message` looks for an attribute named `message` on the class `Tweet`, which doesn't exist.

`a.message` looks for an attribute named `message` on the *instance of `Tweet`, which does exist. (If it did not, it would fall back to looking for an attribute on the type of `a`.)

`a.message = "140 chars"` *always* sets the value of an attribute (creating it, if necessary) on the object `a`. It would never change the value of a *class* attribute, if it existed. For example,

```
class Tweet:
    length = 140

t = Tweet()
t.length = 19

assert Tweet.length == 140
assert t.length == 19
```

The Python language provides no way to declare what attributes an instance of a class will have. *All* instance attributes are created by assignments like `t.length = 19`. Usually, you create the attributes inside the definition of `__init__`, so that they are all created in one place and immediately after the instance is created. Thus, rather than

```
class Tweet:
    pass

t = Tweet()
t.message = "140 chars"
```

you write

```
class Tweet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = "140 chars"

t = Tweet()
```

There is no real difference between the assignments `t.message = "140 chars"` and `self.message = "140 chars"`, beyond when, exactly, they are executed and the name used to refer to the object.